# Print element background css is not overriden after partial page update

Tags: jquery, css, printing

I am using the jquery printElement plugin to print a div of my view. Currently it works fine, but the override css doesn't seem to work if I update the div html with a partial view.

My html construct:

```
<div id="shopfoods">
  <div id="shoplistcontent">
    <table id="shopfoodtable">
```

I got a background image for shopfoods div, but I don't want the background to be shown in printing, so I override the print with another css:

```
$('#printitem').click(function () {
        $('#shopfoods').printElement({
            pageTitle: 'Your Shop List.html',
            leaveOpen: true,
            printMode: 'popup',
            overrideElementCSS: ['../../Content/PrintShopList.css']
        });
    });
```

This works fine, but if I do show other action which causes a partial page update like this:

```
  // ... some ajax call
  success: function (result) {
      $('#shopfoods').html(result);
  }
```

After update, if I click on the print again, the printing will include the background image for the shopfoods. (But, other styling in the print.css works)

I could not figure what is going wrong here, is it the click function, the ajax, the css or this is a plugin bug?

Answer (score 0):

When you recreate #shopfoods (via ajax), your previous plugin initialization of printElement can be lost.

Maybe you need to change $('#printitem').click(...) to $('#printitem').live("click",...)

Look at this: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I think this is correct. Although I need to point out that `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`